# Does ignore option of Pyspark DataFrameWriter jdbc function ignore entire transaction or just offending rows?

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The Pyspark `DataFrameWriter` class has a [`jdbc` function](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.jdbc) for writing a dataframe to sql. This function has an `--ignore` option that the documentation says will:

> Silently ignore this operation if data already exists.

But will it ignore the entire transaction, or will it only ignore inserting the rows that are duplicates? What if I were to combine `--ignore` with the `--append` flag? Would the behavior change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mode("ingore")` is just NOOP if table (or another sink) already exists and writing modes cannot be combined. If you're looking for something like `INSERT IGNORE` or `INSERT INTO ... WHERE NOT EXISTS ...` you'll have to do it manually, for example with `mapPartitions`.